# Python UDP Network not receiving data

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, udp

**Computer A "sender":**

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "computer b ip address"
UDP_PORT 5005
MESSAGE = "HELLO!"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    sock.sendto((bytes(MESSAGE, 'UTF-8')), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

**Computer B "receiver":**

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "computer b ip address"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) 

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print("received: ", data)
```

**Observations**

- I sent data successfully once but have consequently failed despite using the exact setup only moments apart.
- When I loop to send data from computer A to computer B, it disrupts my usb-headphones on computer B only when computer A is sending to the IP Address of computer B.

**Can anyone give me direction in my attempt to send data between computer A and computer B using UDP?**

Comment: Your receiver does not bind to port 5005 and thus will not receive data on this port.

Comment: How does this explain the ability to receive once? What can I do to change it?

Comment: I don't know what you did so that it received once. I'm sure that it will not receive with this code. To fix the code bind the socket to the address where it should receive the data, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

Comment: You're right! I accidentally left that line out when I entered the question. So, why would the problem persist even with this line added?

Comment: The code works for me, so maybe you have some firewall or similar in between the two machines? Try the code on a single machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check telnet serverip 4000 from your machine, to check if 4000 port is reachable.
If not most likely it is firewall issue as pointed by Steffen.